# Represent Email data with respect to time

Tags: time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a bunch of problem tickets that have activity logs in the form of Email-Outbound and Email-Inbound. Outbound is an email sent and inbound is an email received.

I want to identify the pain point of this communication happening with respect to time. But I am not being able to represent the data to detect outliers - outliers being a reply to an email was given after a lot of days.

```
ID Type       Date
1  Outbound   23/4
2  Inbound    24/4
1  Inbound    24/4
2  Outbound   25/4
3  Inbound    29/4
3  Inbound    30/4
1  Outbound   29/6
3  Outbound   2/5
```

I want to spot the second last data point in this sample dataset. See how for ticket 1, Outbound-23/4,Inbound-24/4,Outbound-29/6. I want to investigate why it took two months to reply to an email for ticket 1.

This analysis has to be done with respect to a ticket and I am sitting on >10,000 tickets. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You want to display e-mail incoming date vs. delay of the response. In such case I would simply scatter those two variables against each other.

[image]

The red line on the plot marks the weekly 0.9 quantile (i.e. 90% of e-mails that came in such week were answered up to such delay).

If you have lots of e-mails to visualize, you can group them by delays and condition size of the points on counts of e-mails that came on specific day and were answered with specific delay.

[image]

Code:

```r
R <- 250
# dates
x <- sort(as.Date(sample.int(750, R, replace = TRUE), origin = as.Date("2014-01-01")))
# delays
k <- rgeom(R, 0.05)
# weights
z <- runif(R)

plot(x, k, pch = "+", xlab = "time", ylab = "delay")

yrm <- year(x)*100 + month(x)
yrmDt <- as.Date(sub("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})", "\\1-\\2-01", as.character(yrm)))
delQ <- tapply(k, yrm, quantile, .90)
lines(unique(yrmDt), loess(delQ ~ seq_along(delQ))$fitted, col = "red")


plot(x, k, xlab = "time", ylab = "delay", cex = z*3)
```

Comment: I have tickets... tickets have multiple email inbound outbound communication. I want to concentrate on the TICKETS wherein the communication was anomalous.

Comment: edited the question for more clarity please check

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I do not think that it changes anything if you have tickets vs e-mails, the main point is the same in both cases.

Comment: okk then I will try giving it a shot.. can u share a piece of code for this please?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I made the examples using some random data so I'm afraid that it wouldn't be of much help for the real data. What code are you interested in? The plots are simply `plot(date, delay)` and `plot(date, delay, cex = number.cases)`.

Comment: Just take any programming language (R/Python) and post the code you used I will be able to grasp it :)